# How to pass rvalue reference from caller to callee

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference

Say I have code below

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(std::string && s) { std::cout << s; }

void bar(std::string && s) { foo(s); }

int main() {

  bar("abc");

  return 0;
}
```

I got compiling error:

> error: cannot bind ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ lvalue
>   to ‘std::string&& {aka std::basic_string&&}’  void
>   bar(std::string && s) { foo(s); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::move` from `<utility>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void foo(std::string && s) { std::cout << s; }

void bar(std::string && s) { foo(std::move(s)); }

int main() {

  bar("abc");

  return 0;
}
```

`std::move` is [actually just a little bit of syntactical sugar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), but is the common way of forwarding an rvalue reference.

Comment: So why i need to use std::move here? the parameter i got is &&, and i give it to &&. is that because I cannot assign && to &&? and when i use std::move, literally what happens is not && assigns to &&, but just a move?

Comment: Specifying a named parameter passes an lvalue. With `foo(s)`, the passed parameter is an lvalue reference. lvalue references cannot be converted to rvalue references. `std::move()` is basically the means of converting an lvalue reference to an rvalue reference.